Celery SQS, receiving messages but task not running
I am using fastapi, celery and sqs. Developing on a linux machine.
app/celery.py file
from celery import Celery, Task
import os
import urllib


aws_access_key_id=os.getenv('AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY')
aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv('AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY')
region_name=os.getenv('AWS_SERVER_REGION_KEY')
sqs_queue_url = "https://some-valid-url"

BROKER_URL = 'sqs://{0}:{1}@'.format(
    urllib.parse.quote(aws_access_key_id, safe=''),
    urllib.parse.quote(aws_secret_access_key, safe='')
)

app = Celery(
    "app",
    broker_url=BROKER_URL,
    broker_transport_options={
        "region": region_name,
        "predefined_queues": {
            "celery": {
                "url": sqs_queue_url,
                "access_key_id": aws_access_key_id,
                "secret_access_key": aws_secret_access_key,
            }
        },
    },
    task_create_missing_queues=False,
    broker_connection_retry_on_startup=True,
    broker_connection_retry=True,
    worker_concurrency=1,
)

@app.task(name="do_something", bind=True)
def do_something():
    print("Message received")

Versions
kombu 5.3.7
celery 5.4.0

I can see messages coming in, but my task is not starting on message receive. I have followed this doc on how to setup celery with sqs https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/sqs.html.
Have you guys come across such an issue?
I run my celery app via
celery --app=app.celery worker --pool=solo --concurrency=1 --loglevel=DEBUG --queues=celery -E


Did you try without --pool=solo just to check whether it works in the pre-fork (the default) mode?
